# How to put the Dictionary values to an array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, json, dictionary

I am new to objective-C, please help me to sort out this problem, I have a dictionary something like this

```
Async JSON: (
        {
        "cus_name" = cus1;
        "cus_id" = 001;
    },
        {
        "cus_name" = cus2;
        "job_id" = 002;
    }
)
```

But I need that output same as this:

```
Async JSON:(
        (
        cus1,
        001
    ),
        (
        cus2,
        002
    )
)
```

Please help me how to sort out this, this is the code I have used:

```
 NSData *cityData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];

NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];

__block NSDictionary *json;
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
                           json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                  options:0
                                                                    error:nil];
                           NSLog(@"Async JSON: %@", json);
                       }];
```

Comment: Your response is array not dictionary, I think you want to convert array of dictionary to nested array. right?

Comment: @Nirav D Thanks, Yeah you are right, I need the output in a nested array same as like how i  mentioned above..

Comment: @Rob Thats the requirement i have got, thats why, Please help me to sort out this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making mistake here, your JSON response is not `Dictionary` it is Array of dictionary, if you want to convert it nested array, try like this.

```
__block NSMutableArray *nestedArray = [NSMutableArray array];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                               queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                   completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
                       NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                              options:0
                                                                error:nil];

                    for (NSDictionary* dic in json) {
                        NSMutableArray *subArray = [NSMutableArray array];
                        [subArray addObject:[dic objectForKey:@"cus_name"]];
                        if ([dic objectForKey:@"cus_id"]) {
                            [subArray addObject:[dic objectForKey:@"cus_id"]];
                        }
                        if ([dic objectForKey:@"job_id"]) {
                            [subArray addObject:[dic objectForKey:@"job_id"]];
                        }
                        [nestedArray addObject:subArray];
                    }

                   }];
```

**Note:** As of `NSURLConnection` is deprecated I'm, suggesting you to use `NSURLSession` like this way.

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

[[session dataTaskWithRequest:request 
        completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

     // do stuff and access the data here

}] resume];
```

Comment: Thank you Nirav But I have got an error at this line :nestedArray.addObject(subArray), it says addobject not found in object type of NSMutableArray

Comment: @Tela Welcome mate :)

Comment: I up voted  your answer for your answer and explanation

Comment: @ Nirav D No i clicked it and says accepted, Im sorry im totally new to stack overflow, may be i have made the mistake. Now again I have accepted :)

Comment: @Tela It's ok it happens :) Welcome on SO :)